# How do I override requirements in PBR?

Tags: python, build, distutils, setup.py

I'm trying to package my python code with PBR (Python Build Reasonableness). It generates the requirements metadata for you through a set of conventions.

> The requirement files are tried in that order (N being the Python major version number used to install the package):
>
> requirements-pyN.txt
>
> tools/pip-requires-py3
>
> requirements.txt
>
> tools/pip-requires

In my directory, I need to have a `requirements.txt` for another convention where it's needed for a Docker container that has a different set of requirements than my published target. I want to keep both the Docker image generation and the python package building in this project because they have common files.

How could I specify a requirement such as `requirements-pbr.txt` and override the fact that PBR will pull in `requirements.txt`?

Answer (score 5):

After rooting through the PBR source, I found you can change it through an environment variable. This should do it.

```
PBR_REQUIREMENTS_FILES="requirements-pbr.txt" python setup.py sdist
```

Comment: Thanks for this @myyk.  In case this is useful for anyone's purposes, note that setting `PBR_REQUIREMENTS_FILES=/dev/null` allows bypassing a `requirements.txt` file altogether.

Comment: if you want to use it always like that, add this lines in the `setup.py`

`import os
os.environ['PBR_REQUIREMENTS_FILES'] = 'requirements_pbr.txt'`